# How to apply DataSerializable for ConcurrentHashMap in Hazelcast?

Tags: java, hazelcast

How to apply DataSerializable for ConcurrentHashMap in Hazelcast?

```
public class User implements DataSerializable{
    public User() {
    }

    private Date date;
    private Long id;

    @Override
     public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeLong(this.date.getTime());
        out.writeLong(this.id);
     } 

     @Override
     public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
        this.date = new Date(in.readLong());
        this.id = in.readLong();
     }
}


<hz:serialization>
    <hz:serializers>
        <hz:serializer type-class="java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap" class-name="ConcurrentHashMap" implementation="HashMapStreamSerializer"/>
    </hz:serializers>
</hz:serialization>

User user = new User();
user.setId(1L);
Map<Long, User> concurrentHashMap= new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
concurrentHashMap.put(1L, user);
iMap.put(1L, concurrentHashMap);//IMap is a distributed map of Hazelcast
```

I want to put `concurrentHashMap` to an distributed `IMap` and `User` class already implemented `DataSerializable`.
When I run the code I got following Exception

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `Custom Serializer` for classes that do not implement a DataSerialisable.

First, let's create a simple object.

```
public class Employee {
  private String surname;

  public Employee( String surname ) {
    this.surname = surname;
  }
}
```

Now, let's implement StreamSerializer for Employee class.

```
public class EmployeeStreamSerializer
    implements StreamSerializer<Employee> {

  @Override
  public int getTypeId () {
    return 1; 
  }

  @Override
  public void write( ObjectDataOutput out, Employee employee )
      throws IOException { 
    out.writeUTF(employee.getSurname());
  }

  @Override
  public Employee read( ObjectDataInput in ) 
      throws IOException { 
    String surname = in.readUTF();
    return new Employee(surname);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy () { 
  }
}
```

Full example here: 
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#custom-serialization

Comment: I used HashMapStreamSerializer but still got that exception. I will update my question for the HashMapStreamSerializer  and user class